# How can I speed up a primality checker?

Tags: performance, delphi, primes, pascal

I have a function `FIsPrime` which takes a `int64` and returns a boolean True or False depending on whether the given `int64` is prime or not.

```
function FIsPrime(P:int64):boolean;

  var
  I:int64;
  RSqrtP:Extended;

  begin
    I:= 3;
    RSqrtP := sqrt(P) + 1;

    while ((P mod I) <> 0) AND (I <= RSqrtP) AND ((P mod 2) <> 0) do
      I := I + 2;

    if I < RSqrtP then
      FIsPrime := False
    else
      FIsPrime := True;
  end;
```

However, while this works, it's quite slow. To check the numbers from 10<sup>6</sup> to 5×10<sup>6</sup> takes 4 seconds.

I'm testing numbers on the order of 10<sup>12</sup> and 10<sup>15</sup> - the whole code picks a random number and × it by 10<sup>12</sup> to get a large random number.

This random number is run through the `FIsPrime` function and incremented by 1 untill it is prime:

```
function FFirstPrimeAbove(P:int64):int64;

  var
    BIsPrime: boolean;

  begin
    if P mod 2 = 0 then
      inc(P);

    repeat
      BIsPrime := FIsPrime(P);
      P := P + 2;
    until (BIsPrime);

    FFirstPrimeAbove := P;
  end;
```

This can take a while - around 6 seconds for 10<sup>12</sup> and 7 for 10<sup>15</sup>.

While 14 seconds isn't much, it is annoying. Is there a way to reduce this time with a more efficient algorithm?

I'm fairly new to Pascal, but have been programming for years - so any more efficient algorithm would be useful.

---

I looked at the [AKS Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test#Concepts) but there is a lot of jargon to overcome - "polynomial congruence relation", "generalization to polynomials" and "binomial coefficient" to pick a few.

Any basic hints as to how I could implement something in Delphi would be appreciated.

Comment: This appears to be unrelated to Pascal and Delphi.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I'm writing it is Delphi - so an answer would be written in Delphi. Or do you mean the concept of a fast algorithm is unrelated?

Comment: Well in that case I suggest you do some research. Searching for prime testing algorithms will surely reveal something.

Comment: @Tim. It depends on how often your are going to run this function. If you need it often storing intermediate primes up until the square root of your number may be wort it. For 10**14, you need to store the primes up until 10*7, of which there are approximately 5,761,455 (http://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/doi/10.1007/BF03039306/fulltext.pdf)

Comment: Why did you call your function `FIsPrime`? What is the F for? Assign the bool like this: `somebool := somecondition`.

Comment: @hatchet Thanks, that looks like it will help!

Comment: @JanDoggen That's about 10.5 MB of numbers, which seems like a lot of storage to simply save a few seconds - https://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/millions/ I don't think I'll be running it often enough to make that a reasonable solution - but the context is useful (10^7 is much smaller than my 10^10 estimate)

Comment: Do you want to save time or not? What is our resource budget? How much memory are we allowed to use?

Comment: You should probably remove the algorithm tag since you want this to be a language perf question. It would also be worth saying that you don't want to change the algorithm in any significant way and don't mind if the code is still quite slow.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Removed the tag.

Comment: There's a lot of room to optimize trial division, which may be enough.  Deterministic Miller-Rabin isn't *too* hard to code, can work for all 64-bit inputs, and will definitely be faster once you're in the 10^12 range.  Storing primes other than for micro-optimizing small trial division is probably bad (that is, using the first 1000 is fine, storing millions of them is typically hiding a lack of good code).  AKS is not used in practice as it is extraordinarily slow.

Comment: Brute force optimization: Embarcadero have an example using their Parallel Programming Library (XE7 and onwards). Running your original FIsPrime func in their example on my machine halved the execution time.   http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Tutorial:_Using_the_For_Loop_from_the_Parallel_Programming_Library

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing RSqrtP to Int64 would most likely improve preformance. I didn't test it, but I'd expect comparing a float value to an int64 value not to be the fastest.

Take `((P mod 2) <> 0)` out of the loop.

Also, if you don't mind having a longer initialisation time for your application, you could load a list of all prime between 2 and X and start with them before going to the I+2 routine. You don't need to try to divide by non prime number, as this is already taken care of by prime one (i.e. Anything that can be divided by 4 will be divided by 2, anything that can be divided by 49 will also be by 7, etc)

I posted [an article](http://www.allbitsareoff.com/Programming/?p=6) about optimisation using primes as an example a while ago. Maybe you'll see some more information there that could help you.

Comment: Surely taking the "Is it even" out of the loop will slow it - or do you mean check before the loop, and only enter the loop if it's odd? I guess no need to check every time.

Comment: I guess you just answered your question here.  Right now you are testing some numbers a few thousand times if a number is even or not.

Comment: That reduced it from 14 seconds to 2 seconds - wow! The difference was made in the loop - just taking that `P mod 2` out cut all that off. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the most effective simple way to improve the speed is to create a table of known primes.

There are probably too many primes to store all that fit in a 64 bit integer. But you can store all primes less that `sqrt(high(int64))`. Then when you loop throw possible divisors you can check only against primes. That should provide a very significant benefit.

So, the algorithm is, in outline:

- Fill an array with all the primes less than `sqrt(high(int64))`. This should be pre-calculated.
- To test a value N for being prime, first find its root, `sqrt(N)`.
- Then try to divide primes into the value under test until you reach a prime greater than `sqrt(N)`.
- If you get that far, N is prime. Otherwise if you find a prime divisor, it is not prime.

Comment: Depending on disk access speed and the efficiency of the Sieve of Atkin/Eratosthenes implementation it can sometimes be faster to recalculate the list of primes from scratch rather than load it from disk.

Comment: Definitely something worth benchmarking, and it also depends on your calling pattern (one call vs. many)..  I agree with @rossum that a good SoE will be competitive and possibly faster than reading a file, plus no file to drag around.  Also look into a simple mod wheel.  E.g. time for C code to test the 3614 primes from 10^12 to 10^12+10000:  17.8s odds; 12.0s mod 6; 8.0s mod 30; 4.3s sieve primes; 3.0s static compiled array.  The latter gets very unwieldy with larger examples.  BTW, using BPSW is about 0.007s -- much faster than trial division.